# SQL Query UNION Performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, database-performance, query-performance

## UPDATE

**I think it was premature to ask this. After a few more tests, I found out that the performance has not improved. I will execute a few more tests and post updates here. Till then, don't bother to answer this.**

I had a query like this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 11 [Field_A] 
FROM   [#TempTable] 
WHERE  [Field_A] NOT IN (SELECT bo.[Id] 
                         FROM   [BusinessObject_Table] bo 
                         UNION 
                         SELECT boTemp.[Id] 
                         FROM   [#BusinessObject_Table] boTemp)
```

This query takes forever to run for a sizeable data set. I also added CLUSTERED index on the Id column of the Temp tables, which gave some performance gain, but still, failed to complete.

I replaced this query with this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 11 [Field_A] 
FROM   [#TempTable] 
WHERE  [Field_A] NOT IN (SELECT bo.[Id] 
                         FROM   [BusinessObject_Table] bo) 
       AND [Field_A] NOT IN (SELECT boTemp.[Id] 
                             FROM   [#BusinessObject_Table] boTemp)
```

This completed in seconds. Can someone explain what happened here?

UPDATES:
I thought both the queries are the same. This is what I need.

`BusinessObject_Table has following Ids: 1, 2, 3`

`#BusinessObject_Table has: 3, 4, 5`

`TempTable has rows whose Field_A values are: 1, 2, 3, 4, 6`

The result of the query should be: 6 (Note change in the query above)

I will try to get the query plans and post them here.

Comment: Please post the plans. The queries do different things anyway. The second one checks that it doesn't appear in both tables. The first either table. The first would need to use `intersect` or the 2nd `or` to be the same.

Answer (score 3):

Guessing the in the absence of query plans...

The UNION in the subquery forces a DISTINCT. With separate IN clauses, this is avoided. However, the logic is different between queries (Edit: as Martin Smith noted)

With UNION ALL and a single IN it should be better if this is the logic you want

```
WHERE  [Field_A] NOT IN (SELECT bo.[Id] 
                     FROM   [BusinessObject_Table] bo 
                     UNION ALL
                     SELECT boTemp.[Id] 
                     FROM   [#BusinessObject_Table] boTemp)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should do your query this way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 11 [Field_A] 
FROM   [#TempTable] 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM BusinessObject_Table bo WHERE #TempTable.FieldA = bo.Id
) AND NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM #BusinessObject_Table bo WHERE #TempTable.FieldA = bo.Id
)
```

This way SQL Server can use its optimizer probably a bit better than your UNIONed query. It might very well be that the optimizer will choose to run your query in a different order, based on your indexing strategies and table sizes. Most likely it'll be the fastest way to do this. Though, without table structure and indexes shown and execution plans, it's hard to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for this. The query is fast now. I will test this, and post more comments here later (along with the Execution plans)